# Paypal notify url not working showing latest delivery date in 1985?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

We are having some problems with paypal:

1. Notify url and status appears empty in the message details page.
2. The retry date on the ipn message appears in 1985:

[image]

What can we do to fix this, besides get back in time to catch that retry?

Overview:

- We use basic payments
- We use the notify_url param from a php redirection
- it worked perfectly on sandbox and live, until you updated
- The paypal ipn transaction shows the correct custom parameter

Server side:

Php + custom framework.

Comment: I still am getting this issues, and now i am getting this emails about my server not responding to ipn ... wtf???

Answer (score 2):

There are currently some issues with IPN, that are being addressed that should resolve this issue once they are fixed.  If you would like to be notified once the issue is resolved, you can open up a ticket with [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts).

Answer (score 1):

user1214454: I have the same problem which I have described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174275/why-paypal-does-not-call-my-notify-url-but-on-sandbox-everything-works

I have contacted with PayPal but they said that paypal are sending the IPN messages to my IPN, but they are not being accepted by my IPN, what I think is not true, because when request hit my server e-mail is generated by my script and I know if something hit my server. Besides, as I said in my post in sandbox everything works as expected. I am really frustrated too because my bussiness depends on this.